# Unable to get pick Checkbox from inside of Listview

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am working on this app in which I am having a TextView and a Checkbox inside a list view. The XMLS of a row of ListView is a following:

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <TextView
      android:text="Name"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/deliverNumberTextView"
      android:textSize="20dp"
      android:textColor="@android:color/black"
      android:padding="5dp" />

    <CheckBox
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      android:id="@+id/listviewCheckbox"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

I am trying to pick the value of TextView and Checkbox programatically in the ListView adapter. Following is the code for that, that is written in GetView() override:

```
    public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null)
        {
            row = LayoutInflater.From (_context).Inflate (Resource.Layout.ListviewRow, null, false);
        }

        TextView deliverNumberTextView = (TextView) row.FindViewById (Resource.Id.deliverNumberTextView);

        CheckBox listviewCheckbox = (CheckBox)row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.listviewCheckbox);

        deliverNumberTextView.Text = _deliveries[position].DeliveryNumber;
        listviewCheckbox.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

        return row;
    }
```

The problem is that after this code executes, I get the value of TextView, but I am unable to change the visibility of Checkbox, because "listviewCheckbox" is null.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: deliverNumberTextView is  not null  ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK no, it is not null, but listviewCheckbox is null.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This way ::**

```
public class ListAdapter: BaseAdapter
{

    // Make this variable global
     TextView deliverNumberTextView ;
     CheckBox listviewCheckbox

     public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
     { 
            View row = convertView;

            if (row == null)
            { 
                row = LayoutInflater.From (_context).Inflate (Resource.Layout.ListviewRow, null, false);
            } 

                deliverNumberTextView = (TextView) row.FindViewById (Resource.Id.deliverNumberTextView);

                listviewCheckbox = (CheckBox)row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.listviewCheckbox);

                deliverNumberTextView.Text = _deliveries[position].DeliveryNumber;
                listviewCheckbox.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

    return row;
    } 
}
```

Comment: There is nothing substantial in the error logs related to this. Tried a lot of things, and in the end I changed my strategy. Thanks anyways.